# How to make action menu appears on top of view in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-actionbar-compat

I have a view on top of the `xml layout` as dialog with translucent theme. Currently i am able to click the `action bar` 3 dot icon but menu appears to be going behind the view, so unable to click on `action bar` items.

I've attached the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Let me know if required any further details to look into the issue.

**Any suggestion/ideas would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: i think you have used lock screen code.... remove it and try again

Comment: I've used custom dialog box on which there is a slider button to unlock.